# Is there difference between Number() and Number().valueOf()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've come across an example which tries to check if number is part of a particular range using following code:

```
class RangeValidationBase {
  constructor(private start: number, private end: number) {}
  
  protected RangeCheck(value: number): boolean {
    return value >= this.start && value <= this.end;
  }
  
  protected GetNumber(value: string): number {
    return new Number(value).valueOf();
  }
}
```

what is the use of using `new Number().valueOf()` instead of `Number()`? and are there any cases where using `new Number().valueOf()` is preferred over the other as they both seem same to my noobie brain?

Comment: typeof new Number(3) === 'object'; typeof new Number(3).valueOf() === 'number', this is different

Comment: So numbers are initialised as objects if we create them through new Number()?

Comment: @riskylast that `new Whatever` creates a wrapper object around the `whatever`, hence the use of `valueOf()`. The question is: why not just `Number(value)`? It will return a number straight away.

Comment: new Number('123') return an object like Integer in java, Number('123') return a basic number type like int in java

Comment: Yes! I was curious about the same thing @GerardoFurtado . I've got this from a book and the author uses this method pretty often

Comment: are there any benefits to returning an object like integer? @欧阳斌

Comment: No, you should literally never use the primitive wrappers (they do not behave enough like the primitives they wrap to be more useful than a plain Object). `Number(value)` is much better practice.

Comment: On top of what Ry said: we should obviously respect the knowledge of book authors (I'm a book author myself, but on evolution, not programming). However, we have to be skeptical at the same time. People make mistakes, and sometimes even book authors use anti-patterns.

Comment: There seems to be no differene between the two for various conversion scenarios https://jsfiddle.net/4sz6nhba/1/ So, just use the `Number(n)`. It's readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the use of using `new Number().valueOf()` instead of `Number()`?

None. Their behaviour is the same for all inputs, other than the technicality that `Number` or `Number.prototype.valueOf` could be replaced in a bad environment, which probably makes the `new Number` option harder to optimize for engines and therefore slightly less efficient in practice.

> are there any cases where using `new Number().valueOf()` is preferred over the other

No, except in some misguided in-house style. There *are* good reasons to prefer a simple `Number(value)`:

- the aforementioned behavior technicality
- It’s good practice to avoid primitive wrapper types like the one produced by `new Number()`, because they don’t behave close enough to primitives to be more useful than a plain object that contains a number property (for example), and are generally confusing. Even though the wrapper is immediately discarded in this case, it’s a red flag, picked up by both humans and [linters](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-new-wrappers).